# How to write a Spark dataframe into Kinesis Stream?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, amazon-kinesis

I am creating a Dataframe from a kafka topic using spark streaming.
I want to write the Dataframe into a Kinesis Producer.
I understand that there is no official API for this as of now. But there are multiple APIs available over the internet , but sadly, none of them worked for me.
Spark version : 2.2
Scala : 2.11

I tried using https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-kafka-connector and build the jar. But getting errors due to conflicting package names between this jar and spark API. Please help.

########### Here is the code for others:

```
spark-shell --jars spark-sql-kinesis_2.11-2.2.0.jar,spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.0.jar,spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.10-2.1.0.jar --files kafka_client_jaas_spark.conf --properties-file gobblin_migration.conf --conf spark.port.maxRetries=100 --driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=kafka_client_jaas_spark.conf" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=kafka_client_jaas_spark.conf" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=kafka_client_jaas_spark.conf"

import java.io.File
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils
import org.apache.spark.SparkException
import org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import scala.sys.process._
import org.apache.log4j.{ Logger, Level, LogManager, PropertyConfigurator }
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger

val streamingInputDF =spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","bootstrap server").option("subscribe", "<kafkatopic>").option("startingOffsets", "latest").option("failOnDataLoss", "false").option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT").load()

val xdf=streamingInputDF.select(col("partition").cast("String").alias("partitionKey"),col("value").alias("data"))

xdf.writeStream.format("kinesis").option("checkpointLocation", "<hdfspath>").outputMode("Append").option("streamName", "kinesisstreamname").option("endpointUrl","kinesisendpoint").option("awsAccessKeyId", "accesskey").option("awsSecretKey","secretkey").start().awaitTermination()
```

For the jar spark-sql-kinesis_2.11-2.2.0.jar, go to [quoble](https://github.com/qubole/kinesis-sql) , download the package for your spark version, build the jar.

If you are behind a corporate network, set the proxy before launching spark.
export http_proxy=http://server-ip:port/
export https_proxy=https://server-ip:port/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kafka Connect is a service to which you can POST your connector specifications (kinesis in this case), which then takes care of running the connector. It supports quite a few transformations as well while processing the records. Kafka Connect plugins are not intended to be used with Spark applications.

If your use case requires you to do some business logic while processing the records, then you could go with either Spark Streaming or Structured Streaming approach.

If you want to take Spark based approach, below are the 2 options I can think of.

1. Use Structured Streaming. You could use a Strucuted streaming connector for Kinesis. You can find one [here](https://github.com/qubole/kinesis-sql). There may be others too. This is the only stable and open source connector I am aware of. You can find an example for using Kinesis as a sink [here](https://github.com/qubole/kinesis-sql#using-the-kinesis-sink).
2. Use [Kinesis Producer Library](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:amazon-kinesis-producer) or [aws-java-sdk-kinesis](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:aws-java-sdk-kinesis) library to publish records from your Spark Streaming application. Using KPL is a preferred approach here. You could do `mapPartitions` and create a Kinesis client per partition and publish the records using these libraries. There are plenty of examples in AWS docs for these 2 libraries.

Comment: Thanks Jegan for the answer. With the structured streaming approach, I compiled the jar using the github link you provided. But when I am using that Jar, I am getting error due to the same package name of spark internal library and this jar ( org.apache.spark.sql ) ,when I am reading data from kafka topic prior to writing to kinesis.  Error : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.ContinuousReadSupport

Comment: @Rony I think the jar is not in your application classpath. You may want to add it using the --jars option in Spark submit.

Comment: Yes I have added that in the class path. And I am succeeding when I am writing some handcrafted data into the kinesis stream. But as I have added this 3rd party jar in the class path, the original org.apache.spark.sql is now replaced with this 3rd party one. As a result, when I am trying to do spark.read.format('kafka') , it is throwing error. I have to some how append ( not replace ) this 3rd party classes into the existing spark-sql package org.apache.spark.sql.

Comment: When I downloaded from git, I selected the spark 2.2 branch only, but after running mvn install, it is creating the jar as spark-sql-kinesis_2.11-2.4.0.jar. I dont understand why it is 2.4.0 in the suffix, it should be 2.2 right? And if you see the error : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.v2.ContinuousReadSupport, this class is there in spark 2.4 , not in 2.2 . This might be the problem? Is there something wrong in the pom.xml of the package ?

Comment: You should have both spark-sql-kafka and spark-sql-kinesis jars in your classpath. One should not overwrite the other, I guess something is wrong with your setup. Please double check your classpath and the dependencies.

Comment: It finally worked. Thanks a lot. The problem was, when I was building the jar using eclipse, it was somehow creating spark-sql-kinesis_2.11-2.4.0.jar. But when I ran mvn install from command line, it built spark-sql-kinesis_2.11-2.2.0.jar, which worked successfully. Still I need to figure out why eclipse was building the 2.4 jar with the same project and pom.